# ReactJS - Checkbox doesn't re-render if click-handler is instance method

Tags: reactjs

I prepared a demo on JS Fiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Please, have in mind that in my real world example I have a lot of custom logic - which I've skipped here - that's why some parts of the code in the JS Fiddle (may) look strange.

===

The problem - if you click on the labels - the wrapper and the inner components get updated and rendered correctly.

However - if you click on the checkboxes themselves - then the wrapper gets updated, but the checkboxes doesn't render correctly.

https://jsfiddle.net/dbjfvsm2/5/

At the same time - if I directly call the property handler from the checkbox - then all is fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/dbjfvsm2/6/

I tried with `onChange` as well, but same result.

Why is this happening? ... And I really need to have that instance method - `onItemClick` - that is reused by both the label and the checkbox, this is where some general stuff is happening.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing preventing checkbox to being checked is `e.preventDefault();` in `onItemClick` function. Try removing it and it will work.

```
onItemClick = (e, id) => {
    this.props.handleCheckboxClick(id);
}
```

Why it didn't work? Your answer is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault#Blocking_default_click_handling)

Comment: But any idea why doesn't it work with `preventDefault` ? … Cause the parent component gets updated and the child components get re-rendered …

Comment: @peshohristov I have updated my answer with the link of document. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your fiddle in order to get your desired result

https://jsfiddle.net/sabbin/kh4j1Ltp/12/

You should not use the verification in the child component in the first place, also `e.preventDefault` was causing the an issue in your logic. Also avoid using arrow functions inside the render, you could bind the eventHandler to the class it self

**LE:**
I changed the checkbox logic in the exaple to use a generator, but you can write them one by one

Instead of

```
{checkboxes.map((id)=>(
   <Checkbox
       handleCheckboxClick={this.handleCheckboxClick}
       selected={this.state.selectedCheckboxes.indexOf(id) > -1}
       id={id}
   />
 ))}
```

You can write them directly

```
<Checkbox
    handleCheckboxClick={this.handleCheckboxClick}
    selected={this.state.selectedCheckboxes.indexOf("item-two") > -1}
    id="item-two"
/>
<Checkbox
    handleCheckboxClick={this.handleCheckboxClick}
    selected={this.state.selectedCheckboxes.indexOf(item-one") > -1}
    id="item-one"
/>
```